# For an unlimited time or For unlimited time or other ways

Tags: word-choice, articles

Is there any other way of saying 'unlimited time'? We are giving away a product for free for unlimited time. The actual sentence looks like these:

Now FREE for Unlimited Users for Unlimited Time.

Do I have to add an 'an' before unlimited or just leave it as it is? Or, is there any other way of saying 'unlimited time'?

Comment: It really depends on your context. Why do you need to specify "unlimited users" or "unlimited time" in the first place?

Comment: It's a ridiculous exaggeration anyway - obviously the company would be unable to live up to this promise if 6 billion people asked for the product *tomorrow*, and I seriously doubt it'll be available at all a decade or a century from now, let alone *in perpetuity*. I think this is an Off Topic request for (subjective) opinions on effective advertising copy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a marketing slogan.

Comment: `Is there any other way of saying 'unlimited time'?` Yes: *forever*. And for unlimited users: *everybody*. It _does_ seem to be a boisterous claim though... you will need a potentially infinite supply that keeps up 'till kingdom come to make it stick. I really wonder what you give away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider:

> It's free and always will be.

Comment: This isn't really answering the "an" part of the question.

Comment: @MrHen The OP did ask whether there was another way of saying "for an unlimited time", so this seems to be answering that part of the question.